# Maven resources files after building jar

Tags: maven, resources, build, jar

After building maven project into jar, I get FileNotFoundException. I know that resources files are in the root directory after project being built thus I use this to get my file:

```
final File file = new File("maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp");
```

Here is the exception:

```
C:\Users\ilija\Desktop\MavenizedCP\cp-map\target>java -jar cp-map-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
-shaded.jar

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ilija\Desktop
\MavenizedCP\cp-map\target\maps\ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp (The system cannot fi
 nd the path specified)
```

The working directory here is obviously the directory from which I want to run jar. I guess that working directory should be root of the jar.

Please help here. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where exactly is your ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp file? Is it in C:\maps\ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp or is it part of your maven project in the resources directory?

Comment: It is part of my maven project resources directory!

Answer (score 0):

Your file is then in your classpath. You can try final File file = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("maps/ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp").getFile();

Comment: false Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ilija\Desktop \MavenizedCP\cp-map\target\file:\C:\Users\ilija\Desktop\MavenizedCP\cp-map\targe t\cp-map-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!\maps\ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect) This is what I get after trying your proposal. The first false is due to function file.canRead() which I checked.

Answer (score 0):

THis is how u should get the absolute path for a resource file bundled inside the jar.

```
URI fileURI = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
                .getResource("ParcelsCountyRDMFinal5.shp").toURI();
filepath = new File(fileURI).getAbsolutePath();
```

This works for me..